# wpf localization - locbaml - file is being used by another process

Tags: wpf, localization, locbaml

I have been looking hours for a solution, but I don´t find it.
I want to generate a satellite assembly with following command.

locbaml.exe /generate de/App.UI.resources.dll /trans:MeineRess_de.csv /out:de /cul:de

After executing I get following error:

The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)

Can anybody help me, Thx

Comment: Well, make sure you close all Visual Studios and any other program that might be using the input or output files.

Comment: i restartet the computer and was only executing the locbaml.exe Application. i got the same error

Comment: That is strange. But the `/out:de /cul:de` part looks strange, maybe you're locking your own files. To diagnose, change it to `/out:de /cul:de2` after creating de2, and see what happens.

Comment: Error Message ->
Error: Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
de1 is an invalid culture identifier.

Comment: Is there a better way to localize a wpf application. I am despairing

Comment: Localization for WPF is a little 'rough', it looks unfinished. I just spotted an example that used  `/cul:..\fr` so maybe it is a folder that has to comply with known cultures.

Comment: The same error message like before -> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)

Comment: You need some systematic elimination process now...  I would recreate the folder structure and input files in another place (or a temp project).

Answer (score 0):

Output to a separate folder try for example c:\ this would work

`locbaml.exe /generate de/App.UI.resources.dll /trans:MeineRess_de.csv /out:c:\ /cul:de`

Answer (score 0):

For posterity:
The file name without any command line flag is the original input assembly.  So you're reading in de/App.UI.resources.dll and then /out:de is trying to write to the same file in the same folder.
Probably you want to change de/App.UI.resources.dll to [UiCulture]/App.UI.resources.dll where [UiCulture] is the <UICulture> from your project file, which should match the NeutralResourcesLanguage attribute in your assembly (AssemblyInfo.cs normally).

Perhaps you legitimately want to overwrite the original DLL (though I don't think that makes sense), but this will not be possible as-is because locbaml will load the assembly from file, which holds the file handle open until the application exits.  (Technically until the AppDomain is destroyed.)